# LVM Issue in Virtual Machine

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm

I have a virtual machine (fedora) and connecting to it via ssh. for this VM a virtual disk with 300G volume is assigned, but I cannot add it to VM via LVM, can you help me step by step ? I have only ssh conenction

output of fdisk -l is in below :

```
[root@localhost /]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe27efc6d

Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1          2048     4095     2048    1M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *       4096   618495   614400  300M 83 Linux
/dev/sda3        618496  4812799  4194304    2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       4812800 41943039 37130240 17.7G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       4814848 41943039 37128192 17.7G 83 Linux
```

result of lvmdiskscan:

```
[root@localhost /]# lvmdiskscan
  /dev/sda2 [     300.00 MiB]
  /dev/sda3 [       2.00 GiB]
  /dev/sda5 [      17.70 GiB]
  0 disks
  3 partitions
  0 LVM physical volume whole disks
  0 LVM physical volumes
[root@localhost /]#
```

Comment: Hi, take a step back and explain why `I cannot add it to VM via LVM` please.

Comment: @VlastimilOvčáčík , I mean I could not find a straightway as solution.